# Does using @user in a question or answer send an inbox-notification to that user?

Tags: support, global-inbox

Let's see if anyone can answer this in *under* 4 seconds. I know a notification is sent by using @user in a comment, but what about questions and answers?

I was going to make a fake user and message myself to try it, but I figured a question is the more acceptable way to find out the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, not in questions or answers.

The reason for this is because comments can have multiple people in a 'thread' and we needed a process for addressing a single user.

An answer is only directed at the question asker, so there is no need.  You shouldn't be addressing commenters in answers or questions. (That should be done in comments)

Comment: Okay, I was just going to give credit in an answer, like "as @JJnguy pointed out, ..."  Thanks for the answer.  Though you didn't get it to me in under "4 seconds", so no soup for you!

Comment: @JMC, under 3 minutes is pretty good support.  Sorry to disappoint though. ;)

Comment: @JJn, you knew I was kidding right? _Nowhere_ else <s>on the web</s> anywhere am I'm going to get support that fast. SO is the best hands down.

Comment: @JMC, I knew you were kidding.  Don't worry.  My sarcasm fails to come through in text.  (But I edited it to fix the ambiguity)

Comment: As a corollary, I'd suggest that answers read better when as a completely independent answer, only referencing the question -- after all, it would mean your answer made no sense if the answer you refer to is removed for whatever reason; If you're referring to a comment on your answer, it would be better to add your own comment along the lines of "Thanks @JMCCreative, I've updated my answer accordingly" or whatever...

Comment: @Rowland, agreed

Comment: @jzd, I wonder if you can self notify.

Comment: @jzd appears you can self notify.