# Can you notify a commentor on an answer with @ from within the answer?

Tags: support, notifications, comment-replies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Does using @user in a question or answer send an inbox-notification to that user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74254/does-using-user-in-a-question-or-answer-send-an-inbox-notification-to-that-user)

If someone posts a comment on your answer, and you edit the answer in response and would like to acknowledge the commentor, will a @username within the answer notify them, or do you still need to post a comment in response?

In case there's misunderstanding, this is more about how the messaging system works rather than etiquette.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only notified by @username mentions in comments.

While it makes your edit clear and does acknowledge the contribution it is just that - an acknowledgement.